# Read data from Standard input and find what type it is?

Tags: java

I am trying to read data from the console and find out what type of data type it is, then print some statement if it matches with type.

I have tried like this, but it works for one use case only, can someone correct me what are the modifications do i need.

The code

```
 package euler;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

public class Read {

 public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Object obj = br.readLine();


    if(obj instanceof Integer)
    {
        System.out.println("This input of type Integer");
    }

    else if(obj instanceof Float)
    {
        System.out.println("This input of type float");
    }

    else if(obj instanceof String)
    {
        System.out.println("This input of type String");
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("This is something else");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `readLine()` returns a `String`, your object will always be a `String` . You may want to use `Integer.parseInt(yourString)` and `Float.parseFloat(yourString)` and catch the exceptions .

Comment: It's always a `String`.

Comment: It doesn't work like this. `br.readLine()` always returns a `String`. It's not going to automatically create an `Integer` or a `Float` or any other kind of object depending on what was typed in.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. --> [unclear what you're asking]

Comment: You'll need to try `Integer.parseInt()`, `Double.parseDouble()` and that kind of stuff, and according to the exceptions thrown, decide whether the string you got is a number or not

Comment: @user202729, I am trying to know what type of data type it is based on the given input, then i want to print some statement.

Comment: If the user entered the string `1`, they may indeed want it to be a string. Who says a string can't be `1`?

Comment: Try and catch a parsing exception or use a regex to check the pattern of a numerical value to be able to parse. Because I don't believe trying to parse twice a text value will be efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BufferedReader#readLine()` returns a `String`. You need to do some parsing to determine whether that String represents a valid `Integer` or `Float`.

```
String input = br.readLine();

try {
    Integer.parseInt(input);
    System.out.println("Integer");
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) { // not an int
    try {
        Float.parseFloat(input);
        System.out.println("Float");
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) { // not a float either
        System.out.println("String");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Note that this won't be a problem for a user input but a `String` type will instanciate two exceptions. Using this to read a file for instance should reduce the performance dratsticaly. So I would only use this for a UI usage (like here with the `System.in`)

Comment: @AxelH Good point. A regular expression may be the better option for mass usage like reading from a file.